# How to instance objects including particle system?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, instances

I've searched high and low and couldn't find any answer to a seemingly simple problem. I have a sphere with a particle hair modifier applied and I'd like to instance this multiple times using geometry nodes. The particle hair somehow gets ignored on the instanced objects when rendered with Cycles. How do I do this? Thanks!

[image: Screenshot]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you the reason that your particle system doesn't show up in rendered mode (but does in solid mode). Your approach also seems to work in Evee.

However, it does work if you do it the other way around; rather than adding a Geometry node modifier to the instanced object (PomPom), instead create the mesh (Cylinder) you want to use for distributing the objects and add the Geometry node set-up to that:

[image]